# How do I prove that this complex function can be approximated uniformly by rational functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, approximation, rational-functions

I have the following problem:

> We have $K\subset \Bbb{C}$ a compact subset and $f:K\rightarrow \Bbb{C}$ a continuous function. We take $a\in \Bbb{C}\setminus K$. We assume that there exists a sequence of rational functions $R_n$ with poles in $a$ such that $$\max_{z\in K} |f(z)-R_n(z)|\rightarrow 0$$ Now i fix $k\in \Bbb{N}$ I need to show that there is a sequence of rational functions $Q_n$ with poles in $a$ s.t. $\max_{z\in K} |f(z)^k-Q_n(z)|\rightarrow 0$$

I somehow don't see where to start. I first thought about Runges theorem but there I need a connected set doesn't I?

I also thought about proving it by induction.
I‘m really sorry that I can‘t give you more work, but I have some trubles in working with this approximation stuff. It always seems extreamly frightening to me…

I had the following version of runges theorem:

> Let $f:\Omega\rightarrow \Bbb{C}$ be analytic. Suppose $K\subset \Omega$ is compact. Assume $\Bbb{C}\setminus K=U_0 \cup \left(\bigcup_{i\geq 1}U_i\right)$ where the $U_i$'s are open and connected, $U_0\supset\{|z|>R\}$ and $U_i$ are bounded for all $i\geq 1$. Then pick $a_i$ in each connected component $U_i$ for $i\geq 1$ then there exists a rational function $R_n$ with poles in $(a_i)$ s.t.$$\max_{z\in K} |f(z)-R_n(z)|\rightarrow 0$$

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $M>\max_K |f|$. Then for some $n_0=n_0(M)$, we have $\max_K |R_n|<M$ for all   $n>n_0$.
Now $Q_n=R_n^k$ satisfies, for all   $n>n_0$ and $z \in K$,
\begin{eqnarray}
|Q_n(z) -f(z)^k| &=& \Bigl|\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} R_n(z)^j \cdot f(z)^{k-1-j}\Bigr| \cdot |R_n(z)-f(z)| \\ &\le& 
kM^k \cdot|R_n(z)-f(z)| \,.
\end{eqnarray}
Therefore,
$$\max_{z \in K} |Q_n(z) -f(z)^k|  \le 
kM^k \cdot \max_{z \in K}|R_n(z)-f(z)|  \to 0 $$
as $n \to \infty.$

Comment: Sorry how do you see that we need to write $|Q_n(z)-f(z)^k|$ as a sum, as you did? I quite don't see that

Comment: we use $x^k-y^k=(x-y)(x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}y+\ldots+y^{k-1})$ which is standard and easy to check.

Comment: ah perfect thanks. But if I understood this correclty, the information that the poles of $R_n$ are at $a$ is only useful in this case to say that $Q_n$ has only poles at $a$, i.e. this information is not needed elsewhere

Comment: sorry if I disturb again. I thought about where this proof would fail if we wouldn‘t have no information about neither the poles of $R_n$ nor the one of $Q_n$. In my opinion it would not fail, so I mean it is not necessairly to know where the poles are isn‘t it?

Comment: Right, no information about the poles is needed.  Do you know how to accept an answer?

Comment: Perfect thank you very much for your answer I appreciate that:)